# Не отправляется большой текст в телеграм боте

Tags: python, aiogram

Не отправляется приветственное сообщение в телеграм боте.
Can't parse entities: can't find end of the entity starting at byte offset "1190" python bot

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Пишу на библиотеке aiogram

Comment: Пригласите Вангу, может поможет... Приложите код. Так же проверьте, что в сообщении отсутствуют знаки "*", "_", "&"

Comment: Для начала нужно проверить, есть ли в тексте что-то такое "<", ">" А так, без твоего текста тебе точно ничего никто не скажет

Comment: `Can't parse entities: can't find end of the entity starting at byte offset "1190" python bot` это не про большой текст, в телеге можно остылать 4096 cимволов в 1 меседж, ошибка связана с чем-то другим, нужен код для анализа с сообщением